# In F#, how to pattern match Nullable<DateTime> against Null?

Tags: f#, nullable

(Really confused).

Please assume I have a Visit downloaded from a WCF service as:

```
type Visit = {
               tservice : Nullable<DateTime>
             }
```

and a Visit array consisting of Visits. Assuming some of the visits in the array have a non-null tservice whereas others have a null tservice value, how is tservice pattern matched against null?

i.e. this fails:,

```
let fillSchedule (v:Visits[]) =
       v |> Array.iter ( fun f -> 
                            match f.tservice with
                            | System.Nullable<DateTime>  -> tservice IS null, do something
                            | _ -> tservice is NOT null,  do something
            
                       )
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Nullable` is not an F# type, it comes from the wider .NET, and thus there can be no pattern-matching against it. You can examine its `.HasValue` property to see if it has a value or not:

```
if f.tservice.HasValue
    then tservice is NOT null, do something with f.tservice.Value
    else tservice IS null, do something
```

Alternatively, you can convert it to `Option` via `Option.ofNullable` and pattern-match on the result:

```
match Option.ofNullable f.tservice with
| Some v -> ...
| None -> ...
```

If you have to interop with .NET code that pushes the `Nullable` onto you, this is the best you can do I'm afraid. But if you control the codebase yourself, I would recommend using `Option` instead of `Nullable` to begin with. It can be pattern-matched, and there are some nifty functions to work with it in the `Option` module.

---

Finally, if you really-really need to work with `Nullable`, but also really-really want to pattern-match on it, you can make your own matchers:

```
let (|Null|NotNull|) (n: Nullable<_>) =
    if n.HasValue then NotNull n.Value else Null

// Usage:    
match f.tservice with
| Null -> ...
| NotNull v -> ...
```

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure this out. Perfect answer! Thanks.